# How do I write the contents of a hash to a file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks as follows:

```
character = {"Name: " => "#$name", "Weapon: " => "#$weapon", "Armor: " => "#$armor"}
```

I want to print each **key** and each **value** to a file so that it looks something like this.

Name: Templar
Weapon: Sword
Armor: Heavy Armor

I would like to use a basic method so that I understand what is going on. I've read that there are some modules that do this for you, such as Marshal, but I would like a basic method that involves beginner-level code.

Comment: Are you trying to interpolate the values?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem, then we'll help you fix it. Asking us to write the code is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you. I would recommend reading up more on Files and iterating through hashes yourself first though.

```
yourfile = "/some/path/file.txt"
File.open(yourfile, 'w') do |file|
  character.each{ |k, v| file.write("#{k}: #{v}\n") }
end
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @maxpleaner why the rush?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 because OP already said the answer solved their problem.